# Is it possible to get track previews using MusicKit

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

I want to integrate `Apple` Music into my app, however I don’t want people to have to log in to `Apple` Music. I just want to get the preview tracks of songs.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to use the [Apple Music API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi) to retrieve a song's 30-second preview without the user needing to log in.

1. Get a developer token
2. Issue a request for a song
3. Parse the response to get a Song `previews` URL
4. Playback the song with a streaming media player (e.g. [Howler](https://howlerjs.com/))

Example with cURL:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?term=drake&types=songs&limit=1' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbG...'
```

```
{
    "results": {
        "songs": {
            "href": "/v1/catalog/us/search?limit=5&term=drake&types=songs",
            "next": "/v1/catalog/us/search?offset=5&term=drake&types=songs",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "1384782182",
                    "type": "songs",
                    "href": "/v1/catalog/us/songs/1384782182",
                    "attributes": {
                        "previews": [
                            {
                                "url": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview125/v4/f5/bc/9e/f5bc9e9c-d62b-332b-04c4-061018d060fc/mzaf_7200764193324270096.plus.aac.p.m4a"
                            }
                        ]
...
```

You can play the preview using the browser if you want to:

https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview125/v4/f5/bc/9e/f5bc9e9c-d62b-332b-04c4-061018d060fc/mzaf_7200764193324270096.plus.aac.p.m4a

Comment: Hey can I ask how you created the developer token? I’m having trouble actually getting authorised.

Comment: Hopefully answered your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208428/401-error-when-accessing-musickit-api-via-node-js/56209716#56209716)